# Power outage in just one bedroom of apartment, then every receptacle in one circuit, tried everything. Please Help!

Tags: electrical, wiring, repair, receptacle, circuit-breaker

2/3 duplex sockets stopped working. Replaced them with Leviton 15amp. Did everything correctly, and everything worked for months. Since I had no issues replacing those and every other outlet/ switch in the room since everything was outdated, loose, and a safety hazard.

A few weeks  or so prior to the power outage in bedroom, I tripped the circuit to bedroom multiple times, I assumed it was because I overloaded the circuit by drawing over the amperage limit due to a 9 port power strip. Most of the ports being connected to devices and most of them were powered on at the same time, plus other outlets on that room were also in use. Also had a portable heater plugged in the power-strip and that was also running at that time.

Tried just about everything I could manage:

- Checked and rechecked every outlet/switch  in bedroom made sure The source wasn’t a loose connection that caused this.
- Replaced most upstream outlet. When I finished , I turned on the breaker. Now, the was no power to said outlet, along with entire bathroom within the same path (circuit).
- Have not tampered with any receptacles the bathroom.

I never heard a click when power to the bedroom blew or did it switch to off. So I assumed since the breaker did not trip it narrowed to to either a loose connection on one of the receptacles in the circuit, a wiring issue,or  issues with one of receptacles as a whole. But I’m not so sure anymore.

I recently learned that the switch inside a circuit breaker can only be tripped and reset a finite of time before if stops working.

I’m inexperienced so I had no clue that was a factor. Switch never "clicked" when attempting to reset, so it makes sense that I arced it so many times, that the contacts that control the spring have burnt off. But that wouldn't explain why everything else connected to that circuit continued to work after the bedrooms power blew.

The morning after, I was told by my girlfriend that she had forcefully pressed reset on GFCI 2nd bathroom multiple times out of frustration, told me soon after she did this.  Then both GFCIs in both bathrooms went dead.

Having an electrician fix is out the window. Can't afford. Cannot rely on landlord for electrical or any upkeep since the apartment is not rented by me.  I need to figure this out, at least identify the cause/source. Please help!

After tampering with upstream outlet as of now. Every outlet in the circuit went dead. Total bedroom, master bedroom and one outlet living room.  GFCI socket same circuit in bathroom included.

Oddly, GFCI in other bathroom which was on a different circuit, and other bathroom light switch still has power. Everything else in the apartment is fine.

Summary
Bedroom
3 duplex 2switches(all replaced)(all dead)
Bathroom 
1 GFCI 1 switch(dead)
Living room outlet 
1 duplex outlet (replaced)( dead )

2 (bathroom)
1 GCFI Outlet (dead)

Comment: Try using the side screws instead of the backstabs.

Comment: I just the outlets again 1 of the duplex outtlets I installed has the bare ground wire touching both the neutral terminals. Im fixing it now and I’ll turn on the breaker and see if that was th source this whole time!

Comment: You can help  that with a couple loops of electrical tape wrapped around the sides of the sockets, so the side screws are covered.  A neutral-ground fault will definitely shut down a GFCI.

Comment: Use a digital multi meter to test for power at the panel; one leg at a time, then to individual branch circuits. Sounds like a weak connection somewhere near to the source.